# How to select distinct values from XML

Tags: html, xml, xslt

My question is about XSLT. I am trying to transform XML. This is the first time I am working with XSLT.

I have following XML as an input:

```
<cars>
    <car>
        <model>Accord</model>
        <make>Honda</make>
        <year>2015</year>
    </car>
    <car>
        <model>Highlander</model>
        <make>Toyota</make>
        <year>2011</year>
    </car>
    <car>
        <model>Rogue</model>
        <make>Nissan</make>
        <year>2016</year>
    </car>
    <car>
        <model>Odyssey</model>
        <make>Honda</make>
        <year>2012</year>
    </car>
    <car>
        <model>Camry</model>
        <make>Toyota</make>
        <year>2019</year>
    </car>
    <car>
        <model>Explorer</model>
        <make>Ford</make>
        <year>2017</year>
    </car>
</cars>
```

I am trying to produce following output:

```
<tns:resource technicalType="application" appCode="6Y00">
<tns:make lang="en">Ford</tns:make>
<tns:country name="List">USA</tns:country>
</tns:resource>
<tns:resource technicalType="application" appCode="6Y00">
<tns:make lang="en">Honda</tns:make>
<tns:country name="List">Japan</tns:country>
</tns:resource>
<tns:resource technicalType="application" appCode="6Y00">
<tns:make lang="en">Nissan</tns:make>
<tns:country name="List">Japan</tns:country>
</tns:resource>
<tns:resource technicalType="application" appCode="6Y00">
<tns:make lang="en">Toyota</tns:make>
<tns:country name="List">Japan</tns:country>
</tns:resource>
```

I tried to use a key:

```
<xsl:key name="compMake" match="cars/car" use="make"/>
```

then to sort by make:

```
<xsl:for-each select="cars/car[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('compMake', make)[1])]">
<xsl:sort select="make"/>
<xsl:for-each select="key('compMake', make)">
<xsl:if test="position() = 1">
<tns:resource technicalType="application" appCode="6Y00">
<tns:make lang="en"><xsl:value-of select="substring(normalize-space(make),1,20)"/> 
</tns:make>
<tns:country name="List"><xsl:apply-templates select="country"</tns:country>
</tns:resource>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

But I am getting the whole list of cars sorted by make instead of 4 car-producing companies.
I would appreciate good advice.

Regards,
Mike.

Comment: Trying to morph those snippets and malformed code in a minimal, well-formed XSLT at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jxWZS7F/1 the grouping/distinct part seems to work. I don't see any point in the `<xsl:for-each select="key('compMake', make)"><xsl:if test="position() = 1">` but I don't see how you don't get distinct makes. Perhaps post a full stylesheet together with a full result sample and information about the XSLT processor.

Comment: If you're constrained to use XSLT 1.0, please say so when posting questions (there's an xslt-1.0 tag). If you're able to use more recent versions of the language (2.0 came out in 2007) then there are much better ways of doing grouping.

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT that tried to implement it.
(3) Desired output.
(4) XSLT processor and its compliance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, or 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following XSLT.

The `distinct-values()` function is enough to produce a unique list of car makes. This function requires XSLT processor compliant with XSLT 2.0 standard (circa 2007) or later.

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:tns="url">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
   
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <xsl:for-each select="distinct-values(cars/car/make)">
                <xsl:sort select="." order="ascending"/>
                <tns:resource technicalType="application" appCode="6Y00">
                    <tns:make lang="en">
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </tns:make>
                    <tns:country name="List">
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test=".='Ford'">USA</xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>Japan</xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </tns:country>
                </tns:resource>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output XML**

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<root xmlns:tns="url">
  <tns:resource appCode="6Y00" technicalType="application">
    <tns:make lang="en">Ford</tns:make>
    <tns:country name="List">USA</tns:country>
  </tns:resource>
  <tns:resource appCode="6Y00" technicalType="application">
    <tns:make lang="en">Honda</tns:make>
    <tns:country name="List">Japan</tns:country>
  </tns:resource>
  <tns:resource appCode="6Y00" technicalType="application">
    <tns:make lang="en">Nissan</tns:make>
    <tns:country name="List">Japan</tns:country>
  </tns:resource>
  <tns:resource appCode="6Y00" technicalType="application">
    <tns:make lang="en">Toyota</tns:make>
    <tns:country name="List">Japan</tns:country>
  </tns:resource>
</root>
```

Comment: Thanks to Yitzhak, Martin and Michael for the help. My apologies for posting incomplete information. I am restricted to XSLT 1.0 and I forgot to mention it. This XML transformation is running as a batch job on mainframe.  I tried to use "distinct-values" but got an error "XPathParserException: The function 'distinct-values' was not found."   Regards, Mike.

Comment: Solutions for XSLT 1.0 have a key and for-each loop with generate-id() = generate-id(key(…))[1], but the details of this solution are not clear for me. I would appreciate some clarifications on this.